# How can I split an Observable that emits two types of Lists?

Tags: java, rx-java

I've got an Observable that emits `List<A>` and `List<B>`. I need to process each list through their own sets of logic. I was looking into `groupBy`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210059/918585), but it only caters to different types of emitted items altogether. Seeing as both objects are Lists of different types, that solution doesn't quite help. I also couldn't find anything to determine the type of list (without using reflection).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the return-type of the Observable? Does A and B inherite from the same class? Maybe there is another solution to this. Please provide some code.

Comment: A and B don't inherit from the same class. The Observable is created with `Observable.just(List<A>, List<B>)`

Comment: Can you change the way the observable is created? Seems like your best option would be to wrap these lists in objects that preserve more information about their types at runtime.

Comment: @noppa yes, this is what I ended up doing. I split up the observable into two, with each one emitting its own list, pushing it through the logic and then combining the two via zip (as i still need both lists at once for another call). However, as per the original question I can conclude that emitting 2 lists in an observable and looking to do something with each of them is asking for a headache. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this would be to view the first element of the `List` (if it is nonempty).  With this, you'll be able to determine the type of the `List`:

```
if (list1.get(0) instanceof A) {
    // list1 is of type A
    // list2 is of type B
} else {
    // list1 is of type B
    // list2 is of type A
}
```

Comment: Yea, I've thought of it before. Not the cleanest, and covering cases such as an empty list would make it even less clean. However, that's the only solution that would work so far. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and yeah type erasure makes working with generics at runtime very difficult.